# Vertical separator in between field and its value in Odoo Xml Views

Tags: python, html, css, bootstrap-4, odoo

I have a view xml in Odoo V13. I had a code as below in div tags. I just want a vertical separated pipe or a line separating field name and its value.

View as Below:

```
<group>
<div>
   <div class="row">
       <label string="Website" for="field_id" class="col-lg-5 font-weight-bold"/>
       <field name="web_site" id="field_id" class="oe_inline"/>
    </div>
   <div class="row">
       <label string="Apply on First" for="field_id" class="col-lg-5 font-weight-bold"/>
       <field name="Apply_First" id="field_id" class="oe_inline"/>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
       <label string="Start Date" for="field_id" class="col-lg-5 font-weight-bold"/>
       <field name="start_date" id="field_id" class="oe_inline"/>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
       <label string="End Date" for="field_id" class="col-lg-5 font-weight-bold"/>
       <field name="end_date" id="field_id" class="oe_inline"/>
    </div>
</div>
</group>
```

My Expected O/p:

[image: Image to view Expected Output]

Currently I also see more space between Field Name and its value along with no vertical separator as shown in the image.  I want to reduce the space between field and its value.
I just want to understand if we have any css/bootstrap styling for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you could use css `border` to achieve something like that.

**1 - First way to acheive this:**

Put the `border` property on fields or labels:

HTML:

```
<div>
  <div class=row>
    <label string="Website" for="field_id" class="col-lg-5 font-weight-bold label">Label 1</label>
    <field class="field">Field 1</field>
  </div>
   <div class=row>
    <label string="Website" for="field_id" class="col-lg-5 font-weight-bold label">Label 2</label>
    <field class="field">Field 2</field>
  </div>
   <div class=row>
    <label string="Website" for="field_id" class="col-lg-5 font-weight-bold label">Label 3</label>
    <field class="field">Field 3</field>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.label{
  padding-right: 8px;
  border-right: 1px solid grey;
}

.field{
  padding-left: 5px;
}
```

JSFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/q6t1y3r7/4/

---

**2 - Second way to acheive this:**

Re-organise the divs to have a column display, and put the `border` property on one of them:

HTML:

```
<div>
  <div class="column column-with-border">
    <label string="Website" for="field_id" class="col-lg-5 font-weight-bold label">Label 1</label><br>
    <label string="Website" for="field_id" class="col-lg-5 font-weight-bold label">Label 2</label><br>
    <label string="Website" for="field_id" class="col-lg-5 font-weight-bold label">Label 3</label><br>
  </div>
  <div class="column field">
   <field class="field">Field 1</field><br>
    <field class="field">Field 2</field><br>
    <field class="field">Field 3</field><br>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.column{
  display:inline-block;
}
.column-with-border{
  border-right: 2px solid grey;
}
.label{
  padding-right: 8px;
}
.field{
  padding-left: 1px;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dmwc9sk2/5/

Comment: @aru You're welcome. You can play with the `padding` and `width` properties to settle on spacing.

Comment: When i'm editing the field value. It comes in the next line by breaking the vertical line. How can we make the field stay in same row while editing it ?

Comment: I used the first one.When im editing the field, it is coming in next line by breaking the vertical line. How can we avoid it ?

Comment: I think you should try using the second way, it was a better solution IMO

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work as expected. Anyway thanks for your help. I'll try posting as a new question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221639/discussion-between-aru-and-shiverz).